# Excel VBA using Selenium - Select Chrome Web DropDown List

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Complete my VBA code before the "EndIf" line. Please help me select the Gender from below Target Inspect HTML code .
Below is my code which I have written till now. Please help to complete it.

```
Sub google_search()
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 2
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "https://abcd.com/"     



    bot.FindElementbyName("patient_name").SendKeys "Value"
    bot.FindElementbyName("patient_id").SendKeys "Value"

    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 4) = "Years" Then
       bot.FindElementById("age_year").Click
       bot.FindElementbyName("age").SendKeys "Value"
    Else
    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 4) = "Months" Then
       bot.FindElementById("age_month").Click
       bot.FindElementbyName("age").SendKeys "Value"
    Else
    End If
    End If

    If Sheet1.Cells(row, 6) = "M" Then
    
        ...........................................................
        
    End If

 


    Stop

    End Function
```

**Target Site as this inspect**

```
<div class="form-group">

<label for="gender">Gender</label><span class="text-danger"><b> *</b></span>

<select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">

<option value="">Select Gender</option>

<option value="M">Male</option>

<option value="F">Female</option>

<option value="T">Transgender</option>

</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing 2 times End If, which will throw an error. This should be your correct code.

```
Sub google_search()
Dim row As Integer
row = 2
Dim bot As WebDriver
Set bot = New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome"
bot.Get "https://abcd.com/" 

bot.FindElementbyName("patient_name").SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(row, 2).Value
bot.FindElementbyName("patient_id").SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(row, 3).Value

If Sheet1.Cells(row, 4) = "Years" Then
    bot.FindElementById("age_year").Click
    bot.FindElementbyName("age").SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(row, 5).Value
ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(row, 4) = "Months" Then
    bot.FindElementById("age_month").Click
    bot.FindElementbyName("age").SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(row, 5).Value
End If


If Sheet1.Cells(row, 6) = "M" Then
    Dim GenderDD As Selenium.WebElement
    Set GenderDD=bot.FindElementById("gender")
    GenderDD.AsSelect.SelectByText(Sheet1.Cells(row, 6).value)
End If

 


Stop

End Function
```

Comment: Please make focus on doted lines (just before the EndIf) .. I want to choose Gender from Excel to Web by Selenium Bot.
what you said is not even an error.

Comment: Now we are focusing on the real matter,
it's showing error in that specific line "Syntax Error - Compile Error"
is any library cmd added in beginning codes ?

Comment: i have changed slightly as below Dim Element As Selenium.WebElement
    Set Element GenderDD=bot.FindElementById("gender"). check now

Comment: Compile error- Expected: =
highlighting on GenderDD

Comment: here is the change  Dim GenderDD As Selenium.WebElement
        Set GenderDD=bot.FindElementById("gender")
        GenderDD.AsSelect.SelectByText(Sheet1.Cells(row, 6).value)

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: @JosephJohn: If it helped you kindly upvote my answer

Comment: please give codes to run same requirement via <option value="M">Male</option>

Comment: if you want to selectby text "Male then change this to GenderDD.AsSelect.SelectByText("Male") or pass the column value where you stored the Value as Male. eg. GenderDD.AsSelect.SelectByText(Sheet1.Cells(row, 7).value) where you stored in 7 the column  and 2nd row the value as Male